My bot can't seem to click on an website button
I am trying to use my python and selenium to click on a button changing the talk method from generative to neural on AWS Polly. I have tried the x-path and the selector for multiple variations of the element but I cannot seem to get it to click. (https://i.sstatic.net/f5xQRG86.png)(https://i.sstatic.net/mdKYgXHD.png)
Here is the code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

# Configure Chrome WebDriver path
chrome_driver_path = "C:/Users/trave/Downloads/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver.exe"

# Path to Chrome user profile
user_data_dir = "C:/Users/trave/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data"
profile_dir = "Profile 4"

# Setting up Chrome options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={user_data_dir}")
chrome_options.add_argument(f"--profile-directory={profile_dir}")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

# Initialize the WebDriver with Chrome options
service = Service(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

try:
    # Open the AWS Polly Synthesize Speech page
    polly_url = "https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/polly/home/SynthesizeSpeech"
    driver.get(polly_url)

    print("Waiting for the 'Next' button...")
    next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/button"))
    )
    next_button.click()
    print("Clicked 'Next' button.")

    print("Waiting for the 'Sign In' button...")
    signin_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[5]/button"))
    )
    signin_button.click()
    print("Clicked 'Sign In' button.")

    WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
        lambda d: d.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete'
    )
    print("Page loaded.")

    # Try interacting with the element using different methods

    # Method 1: Using XPath
    try:
        neural_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/main/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/span/span/span[1]/input'))
        )
        neural_button.click()
        print("Clicked the 'Neural' button using XPath.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to click using XPath: {e}")

    # Method 2: Using CSS Selector
    try:
        neural_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#\\36 6-1725057032906-3969'))
        )
        neural_button.click()
        print("Clicked the 'Neural' button using CSS Selector.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to click using CSS Selector: {e}")

    # Method 3: Using JavaScript
    try:
        neural_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#\\36 6-1725057032906-3969')
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", neural_button)
        print("Clicked the 'Neural' button using JavaScript.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to click using JavaScript: {e}")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

finally:
    #Close the browser after a delay
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.quit()

After running this I don't receive any error messages nor any prints. I cannot for the life me figure out why.
